# My usercontrol (.dll) not displaying in the toolbox of webproject

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I created a winform User Control, that gave me a dll.  I added this dll to the toolbox of my web project (right clicked toolbox, Choose Item and added my dll)
But it does not display it in the toolbox.  I have searched over net, the usercontrols made in winforms can be used in webforms.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Is the control within a Windows Control Library? (Not a bog standard Class Library?)

Comment: I created it using Windows Forms Control Library.  Is it what you are asking?

Comment: Yes.  Tbh - having a quick dive into some docs it seems you should not be adding the .dll to the solution as a reference nor into the toolbox, but by copying the DLL to BIN directory and referencing it through the Object Tag.  With no direct link to the control NOR the way it renders, it sounds like placing it into the Toolbox might not be possible.

Comment: Thanks ! I have created the dll but do not know how to Tag it.  Could you do me a favour and explain a bit...

Answer (score 0):

[For the benefit of the knowledgebase]

You cannot add the control through the Toolbox nor as a reference.  You copy the DLL to the BIN directory and reference the control through the object tag, e.g.

```
<object id="MyCustomWinControl" classid="http:MyWindowsControlLibrary.dll#MyCustomWinControl.MyControl" height="100" width="300" VIEWASTEXT/>
```

where 'MyWindowsControlLibrary.dll' is the filename of the DLL, 'MyCustomWinControl' is the Assembly namespace and 'MyControl' is the qualified name of your control.  Check out this [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20210619191631/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/052604-1.aspx) for example, although I would imagine you will require the client to have .NET installed (preventing Mobile and Linux users from using your page).